# WebClient.UploadValues is not making a post request in c#

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to upload a single jpeg image to a PHP script. This my console app `program.cs`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        string result = UploadHandler.Post(
            "http://localhost/upload_test",
            "frame.jpg"
        );

        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);

        Console.WriteLine("Result : {0}", result);
        Console.WriteLine("File uploaded in : {0}", elapsedTime);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This is my `UploadHandler` class:

```
class UploadHandler
{
    public static string Post(string serverUrl, string filePath)
    {
        string result = "";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues(serverUrl, new NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "frameData", ToBase64(filePath) }
            });
            result = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static string ToBase64(string filePath)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(
            File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)
        );
    }
}
```

and this is my php script that receives the upload:

```
<?php

if (count($_POST) && isset($_POST['frameData']))
{
    file_put_contents('frame.jpg', base64_decode($_POST['frameData']));
    exit("OK");
}
else
{
    print_r($_POST);
    exit("INVALID REQUEST");
}
```

And this is the response I get:

[image]

Any idea why this might be? It appears the C# app isn't making a HTTP POST request.

Comment: Try looking at your request with something like Fiddler.

Comment: I used `Wireshark` to monitor all HTTP request and did a test and i was not picking up any HTTP request at all... which seems bizarre because I am getting a response back.

Comment: Is the server in this case on the same machine as the .Net app? In that case you need to address the server by the machine name, not `localhost`, as .Net doesn't really send something over the network interface when addressing `localhost`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836655/cant-see-webclient-post-request-in-fiddler).

Comment: My .NET app and my `WAMP` server is on the same machine. I removed `localhost` and replaced it `127.0.0.1` and it's still getting the same response back `INVALID REQUEST`

Comment: It won't change anything about the response - it's just so you can capture the request in Fiddler (or something else). But my guess is that `127.0.0.1` is not proxied, either. Try using your machine's name.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
client.UploadValues(serverUrl, "POST", new NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "frameData", ToBase64(filePath) }
            });
```

EDIT:
You should debug issues like this with Fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

First make sure that your C# app sends the expected request by inspecting it in Fiddler, and then you can make sure that your PHP app is doing the right thing on the other end.

Right now you won't get very far, because it is not clear where the problem is.

Comment: I edited my comment, I think you should use Fiddler and be able to quickly identify the issue.

Comment: Getting nothing on fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

C# Side

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string URL = "http://localhost/phppost/upload.php";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("31.jpg");
        String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["user"] = "Brasd1";
        formData["pass"] = "85s1a";
        formData["name"] = "31.jpg";
        formData["image"] = file;

        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
        webClient.Dispose();

    }
```

PHP Side

```
<?php

$user = isset($_POST['user']);
$pass = isset($_POST['pass']);
$name = isset($_POST['name']);
$imag = isset($_POST['image']);

if ($user === 'Brasd1' && $pass === '85s1a' && $name != '' && $imag != '') {
    base64_to_jpeg($_POST['image'], $name);
} else {
    echo "Error user pass file";
}

function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file)
{
    $ifp = fopen('uploads/' . $output_file, "wb");
    fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($base64_string));
    fclose($ifp);
    return ($output_file);
}
?>
```